# How to save a bitmap image in a file/folder directories in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1

I want to save an image in my folder name Photos in my application.I pick an image file using FilePicker and shown in an image control on button click I want to save it in a directory.How can I do that.I have perforned to save picture library but unable to save in a folder.Can any one provide sample code?

```
 RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
       await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(MyCanvas);
       //StorageFile saveFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("sample.jpg");
       StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
      StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

       var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();


       using (var fileStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
       {
           var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);

           encoder.SetPixelData(
               BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
               BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
               (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
               (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
               DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
               DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
               pixelBuffer.ToArray());

           await encoder.FlushAsync();
```

Comment: Can you show some code where you have tried to save the picture? If I understood correctly you 'have performed to save icture in the library' - what library, how it was done, where do you encounter problems when trying to save to a folder, and what kind of folder?

Comment: I have a folder name Profile pics where all images shuld be saved and there paths shuld be saved in the database

Comment: Where do you have this folder: SD, Phone, Isolated Storage? Are you targetting Silverlight or WinRT? And what about this code?

Comment: In my project and WinRT

Comment: I guess you obtain a *StorageFile*, thean have you taken a look at [await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br227193)?

Comment: Yes but I dont want to save in Isolated Storage

Comment: So where do you want to save it? If you mean package - then you can do it only in VS, once you deploy the app, those files/folders are readonly.

Comment: I have updated my question what I have to edit if I want to save in a folder in isolated storage.

Comment: You have to edit the destination folder - take a look [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx).